# Function only setting values once?

Tags: c++, function

I'm generating random positions for meshes and checking that they aren't too close to another mesh before setting the generated positions as their final positions. The code works when not used in a function call, but when done through a function call, only generates one set of positions.

Can anyone explain why this happens?

Comment: You use `call by value`, use `call by reference` instead. Otherwise you copy your parameters instead of passing a reference like you intended.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're copying the `std::vector` instances into the `generateTargets` function, therefore you won't see any change to the original vectors from the caller side.

The simplest solution is to pass them *by reference* instead:

```
void generateTargets(
    std::vector<glm::vec3>& positions, 
    std::vector<glm::quat>& orientations, 
    int targetNum) { // ...
```

---

Otherwise, you could return an `std::tuple` of vectors to maintain function purity. This will very likely not incur any extra cost due to *move semantics* and RVO.

```
auto generateTargets(
    std::vector<glm::vec3> positions, std::vector<glm::quat> orientations, int targetNum) 
{
    // ...
    return std::make_tuple(std::move(positions), std::move(orientations));
}
```

Usage:

```
std::vector<glm::vec3> positions(targetNum);
std::vector<glm::quat> orientations(targetNum);
auto result = generateTargets(std::move(positions), std::move(orientations), targetNum);
```

Comment: Can't believe I missed that! Thanks for the simple solution :)

Comment: A bit unrelated, but is there a simple way of saying "if x = x + 'anything up to and including y'", rather than checking it's equal to x + 1, x + 2 and so on?

Comment: uh... `x <= x + y`?

Comment: I am an idiot, too much programming in one day... my bad.

Comment: @JackPhipps: if you feel like my answer solved your problems you should **mark it as accepted**.